# Refer to variable based on another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had the following code:

```
var number = 3;

var value1 = 22;
var value2 = 50;
var value3 = 63;
```

You can see that `number = 3` and so from this I would like to get the value of `value3` and say if `number = 2;` I would like to get the value of `value2`.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Is it feasible to use an array instead? Or must they be variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array instead, if possible.

```
var values = [22,50,63],
number = 2;

console.log(values[number]);
// 63
```

If this is not the case then the only other way I can think of is using `eval` which has some risks associated with it.

Try:

```
var number = 3;

var value1 = 22;
var value2 = 50;
var value3 = 63;

eval('value' + number);
// 63
```

If they are global objects then they may already be available as a key on the window object:

```
window['value3']
// 63
```

Which means you can concat the string in the key name:

```
window['value' + num]
// 63
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use an array to store the data.